# Check multiple header using Scalastylesheet org.scalastyle.file.HeaderMatchesChecker

Tags: java, scala, maven-plugin, licensing, scalastyle

Whenever we build a new class on top of open source, we usually add our own licence (instead of the apache one, which is there by default in our open source project).
Now the problem is scala style sheet checks for headers using org.scalastyle.file.HeaderMatchesChecker for Apache licence (it's hard coded as it's an open source apache project).

Now i want to make a change and allow the scala style, if any of the 2 licence work. example below

Apache Licence
/*
* Licence to Apache
* some other info
* url
*/

Custom Licence
/*
* Licence to SomeLicence
* some other info
* url
*/

I want the style to pass if any of these 2 licence is available in header.
I've already added this licence to RAT plugin, but need this in scala as well.
i tried adding another entry of `<check level="error" class="org.scalastyle.file.HeaderMatchesChecker" enabled="true">`
but that doesn't work`

I want to add 2 different licence check,  an or style check . i tried below

```
       <parameter name="regex">true</parameter>
       <parameter name="header">(<![CDATA[/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements. 
 * ......
 */]]>)|(<![CDATA[/*
 * Licensed to the Some Other Foundation (SOF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements. 
 * ......
 */]]>)
</parameter>
```

even this doesn't work.